# error: No profile for team '***' matching 'match AdHoc com.reddwarf.musicapp' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching

Tags: ios, xcode, github-actions, fastlane

when I build the flutter app in GitHub Actions using this command:

```
flutter build ios --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

shows error like this:

```
Run flutter build ios --release --no-sound-null-safety
Building com.reddwarf.musicapp for device (ios-release)...
Upgrading AppFrameworkInfo.plist
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ***
Running pod install...                                              3.7s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                            7.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    error: No profile for team '***' matching 'match AdHoc com.reddwarf.musicapp' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '***/match AdHoc com.reddwarf.musicapp'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Encountered error while building for device.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

why this happen? I could build in my local machine XCode successs.

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-sound-null-safety                                                           ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Changing current working directory to: /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/flutter-netease-music
Building com.reddwarf.musicapp for device (ios-release)...
Upgrading AppFrameworkInfo.plist
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 6JP4P88ZJB
Running pod install...                                           2,528ms
Running Xcode build...
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        18.0s
Xcode build done.                                           140.2s
Built /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/flutter-netease-music/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
(base)
```

But I could not build in GitHub Actions, what should I do to fix this build problem? This is the local xcode config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found we should not sign in build, the GitHub Action did not contains provision file:

```
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --no-sound-null-safety
```

then sign the app using Fastlane the next step.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --no-sound-null-safety`
This solution helped me (without `--no-sound-null-safety`)
Thank you *Dolphin*